# Azure AD OAuth - User in multiple directories and GraphAPI

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

let's say I have a identity (foo) that lives as a 'member' in **directory1**, but is also added as (ext) global administrator in **directory2**.

Also, we have a company that has released a multi tenancy app that requires permissions to do something.

**EDIT. Clarifying**

Now, when the oauth flow is initiated, we don't know about foo's tenancy/s, therefore we redirect him to `/common`. The resulting scenario, from what we could observe, is foo authenticating and granting permission in **directory1**.
If, changing `common` to `directory2`, the grant is performed in the guest directory and the application is granted authorizations in **directory2**.

How can we prompt foo to pick in which directory authenticate (if multiple) not knowing his tenancies upfront?
Shouldn't the /common endpoint, ask foo for which directory he is authorizing?

I have looked also at some documentation mentioning graph api vs microsoft graph. in the graph api seemed possible to pass a tenancy as the first part of the url. How the grants work there? If I have authorized the app in directory1, how can I put directory2 as target and being authorized reading there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that /common will authenticate the user against their home tenant always (unless they have an active session in another). If you want that user to auth against a specific tenant, you need to specify that instead of common. There is also no public API to list tenants AFAIK :/ So for things like admin consent, I'd recommend using a local account instead of a guest.

Comment: The admin permission was an example, it is not the core of the issue here. The real problem is not knowing the tenancy of the end user we are trying to get permission from, therefore redirecting them to /common. The user ideally should be prompted against which directory wants to authenticate, instead of the home one. I don't see otherwise a way for them to give their consent in the guest directory